# discord.js better-sqlite3 command running without the command being executed

Tags: node.js, discord.js, better-sqlite3

Okay, so below is my code to create a database with the balance $0, and underneath that is a test command to test out two argument so that I can get a return message of:

BOT: "${args} ${args2}"

However, whenever I got to test out the command with the two argument definitions, I get an error saying `SqliteError: no such table: a` (I typed in the command `eco test a b`, "a" being ${args} and "b" being ${args2}.

```
client.on("message", message => {
  if(message.author.bot) return;
  const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === "testbal") {

  const table = sql.prepare(`SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name = '${args}';`).get();
  if (!table['count(*)']) {
    // If the table isn't there, create it and setup the database correctly.
    sql.prepare(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${args} (bal TEXT);`).run();
    // Ensure that the "id" row is always unique and indexed.
    sql.prepare(`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_${args}_id ON ${args} (bal);`).run();
    sql.pragma("synchronous = 1");
    sql.pragma("journal_mode = wal");
  }

  // And then we have two prepared statements to get and set the score data.
  client.getScore = sql.prepare(`SELECT * FROM ${args} WHERE bal = ?`);
  client.setScore = sql.prepare(`INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ${args} (bal) VALUES (@bal);`);
  sql.prepare(`INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ${args} (bal) VALUES (0);`).run();
}

});

//Actual command now

client.on("message", message => {
  const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    if (command === "bal"); {
        if (message.author.bot) return;
        const data = sql.prepare(`SELECT bal FROM ${args}`).get();
      message.channel.send(`You have ${data.bal}`)
  }
});

//TEST ARGS

client.on("message", message => {
    const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
    const args2 = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim(args).split(' ');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    if (command === `test`); {
        message.channel.send(`${args} ${args2}`);
    }
});
```

The error comes from `` const data = sql.prepare(`SELECT bal FROM ${args}`).get(); `` according to the console, which is strange since I did not execute the `bal` command at all, and only did the `test` command which is not part of the code where `` const data = sql.prepare(`SELECT bal FROM ${args}`).get(); `` is at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a semicolon between your if statements and the actual block of the statement, which is making it so it always runs.

Take this example, we know `if (false) {}` should do nothing, but because there's a semicolon it does:

```js
if (false); {
  console.log('This shouldn\'t be logged, but it is.');
}

if (false) {
  console.log('This doesn\'t get logged.');
}
```

Comment: Out of all of the things to forget, it just had to be the semicolon.... alright thanks!